# Dynamically loading a template leaves the old template / scope on the page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We're trying to dynamically load and compile DOM elements for the sake of AB testing in angular. So far, this code works pretty well:

```
MyApp.directive('testing',
['$http', '$templateCache', '$compile', '$window', 
function($http, $templateCache, $compile, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function(scope , elm, iAttrs) {
                    var test = iAttrs.testing

                    //Ensure the test is in place
                    if ( typeof angular.testing[test]== "undefined" || !angular.testing[test].template )
                        return false;

                    //Build the template path
                    var tmpName = "/angular/app/testing/"+test+"/"+angular.testing[test].template+".html"

                    //Hide the original template so the change doesn't flash
                    angular.element(elm).css('display', 'none')

                    //Retrieve the new template
                    $http.get(tmpName, {cache: $templateCache}).success(function(tplContent){
                        //Compile it
                        var compiled = $compile(tplContent)(scope)
                        //Replace the element with the new compiled template
                        elm.replaceWith(compiled)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}])
```

You can then apply it on things like this:

```
<div testing="mytest"></div>
```

And your testing software can set variations with something like this

```
angular.testing.mytest = {template: "newtest"}
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the element that's being replaced is still present on the page (though hidden somewhere - I don't actually see it, but I can find it with some debugging), and it's causing some internal directives to fail. Also, trying to remove it or null it out doesn't have any effect.

Any advice?

Comment: Please reproduce this in plunker. I'm not sure what it means that an element is "hidden somewhere... but I can find it with some debugging". Also, what is the "original template"?

Comment: @NewDev Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YtQknR3FXaxKwhfXXKCO?p=preview. To see what I'm saying, open up the console and click on "New" -- there should only be one element firing the off-click plugin, but the original element fires also. That's the root of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that even though you remove the subtree from the DOM you never de-register the click handler that `offClick` sets on the document.

Specifically,

```
scope.$on("$destroy", ...)
```

never fires since the scope is never destroyed.

Use, instead, `elm.on("$destroy", ...` to de-register the click handler:

```
elm.on("$destroy", function(){
  $document.off('click', handler);
});
```

**Off-topic**:

1. Are you sure that you need to set the click handler on the `document` with each `offClick`? If you had two of these, each would set a handler.
2. I don't recommend extending the `angular` object with your own properties. I'm referring to `angular.testing = {}`.

Comment: Huge! That worked. It definitely seemed odd that the element still existed despite being replaced. Thanks.